# Groupon API for statement

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to echo out all the titles of every deal it comes across in their deals section. I am guessing the for statement is halfway correct and that I am some how not looping the print statement to run through all the titles as well. But I am just not sure how?

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.groupon.com/v2/deals.json?client_id={accesstoken}&division_id=new-york',
        data: 'client_id='+ access_token + '&' + 'division_id'+ loc,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            items = data;
            // title = data.deals[0].shortAnnouncementTitle;
            console.log(items)
            handleResult(items)
            // handleResult(title)
        },
    });

    function handleResult(items) {
        for(var i=0; i<items.deals.length; i++) {
            var title = items.deals[i].shortAnnouncementTitle;
            s = "<h2 class='results'>" + title + "</h2>";
            console.log(title)
        }

        $("#result").html(s);
    }
```

Currently it loops through and prints out only the last item in the list while in the console I see every title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These should both work, you were overwriting the value of s in each iteration, you were trying to build a larger string but missed the plus:

```
    function handleResult(items) {
    var s = "";
    for(var i=0; i<items.deals.length; i++) {
        var title = items.deals[i].shortAnnouncementTitle;
        s += "<h2 class='results'>" + title + "</h2>";
        //or s = s+ ....   
        console.log(title)
    }

    $("#result").html(s);
}
```

also you should declare the variable 's' using var before its use otherwise you will be setting the global 's' property, or something along those lines, which would create interesting artefacts if s is used else where without a var too :-)

```
    function handleResult(items) {
    for(var i=0; i<items.deals.length; i++) {
        var title = items.deals[i].shortAnnouncementTitle;
        var s = $("<h2 class='results'></h2>").text(title);
        $("#result").append(s);
        console.log(title)
    }
}
```

the above would be my preferred solution as it would give you more control over each element and give a bit of flexibility. I think i've written it correctly above.

Hope that helps. 
Matt